# Dynamic offset selection Array

Tags: excel, vba, compilation

I'm collating data entered to multiple forms that are stored on a network location.
I have up to 10 rows (26 columns) that need to pasted into a collation sheet.

I'm attempting to copy this array and paste to a collation workbook.

Through luck more than skill I have pieced together a load of code to present each file in turn. So my code is horrific to look at
I have used a select solution to count the number of rows for the array.

```
For P = 0 To ct1 - 1

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FoundFiles(P)

DIM bulk as range   

   Sheets("bulk_data").Visible = True
   Sheets("bulk_data").Activate

   With ActiveSheet
blk = 0
   Range("B2").Select
    Do Until Selection = ""
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
        blk = blk + 1
    Loop
```

Now I'm want to copy "B2:Z(blk)" and paste it to the next blank row in the destination file

I thought

```
bulk = Selection.Offset(Range("b2"), 0, blk, 26)
```

would work but it doesn't.

Once I have that array I want to paste (parse?) it to the latest blank row in the collation sheet.

```
Workbooks(DataBaseName).Activate
    Sheets("Input Tab").Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    Do Until Selection = ""
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

bulk.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

next p
```

I would like the BULK array to be pasted into the other sheet but

Comment: Give this a read to clean up your code a little. Unrelated to your question https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate

Comment: You're not making an array in your code. Once declared, you can populate an array with eg `myArr(0) = Range("A2").Value`. Read more here: https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate

Comment: Thanks. Its frankencode at the minute. Its so full of commented out stuff it would make a purist vomit.

Comment: That's how I started, total mess!